# GWT LayoutPanel freezing hyperlink

Tags: gwt

I am new to GWT.

I have a complex page with several components. I am using MVP and UiBinder for my project.
My problem is that Hyperlinks (breadcrumbs) in the page aren't functioning now, it's as if they are just text.

I checked nicely, there is no problem in presenter/event-handling etc. It seems to me it is a design issue. I'm not able to figure it out.

Can you guys please help me.

Thanks

Comment: I solved the issue by using DockLayoutPanel.

Answer (score -1):

Depending on your architecture there are two solutions:

A) you are using Places/Activities:
In that case keep using the HyperLink widget but add a TargetHistoryToken attribute
As the project module isn't given I can only guess the markup isn't done and you should add a .gwt-Hyperlink { } to your css.

B) you are not using Places/Activities:
Use an Anchor and set the href attribute